# Why does D3.js transition function gets broken when I try to use it second time?

Tags: google-chrome, animation, d3.js, transition

I am trying to fade and move an html div to a svg circle element, while same svg circle element fades in to view. Why do I face following problems ?

*The problems I face are :*

- svg circle elements does not fade in
- when I try to use transition second time for div element it does not work
- Even, cancelling transition by `d3.select(textbox).transition()` does not work

*My current setup is :*

- Chrome Version 51.0.2704.36 beta-m (64-bit)
- src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.3/ace.js"
- src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"

*My code is :*

```
c=d3.select(document.body).append("svg")
.append("circle")

c
.attr("r","20")
.attr("cx","50")
.attr("cy","50")
.attr("fill","red")
.attr("stroke","black")
.attr("opacity","0")
.transition()
.duration(200)
.attr("opacity","1");



d3.select(testbox)
.transition()
.style("left",c.attr("cx"))
.style("top",c.attr("cy"))
.style("opacity","0")
.duration(200);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `position` property of div as `absolute`.

Here i sthe working code snippet.

```js
var c = d3.select(document.body).append("svg")
  .append("circle")

c.attr("r", "20")
  .attr("cx", "50")
  .attr("cy", "50")
  .attr("fill", "red")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("opacity", "0")
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("opacity", "1");

var testbox = d3.select("#testbox");

d3.select(testbox.node())
  .style("position", "absolute")
  .transition()
  .style("left", c.attr("cx") + "px")
  .style("top", c.attr("cy") + "px")
  .style("opacity", "0")
  .duration(1000);
```

```css
div {
  background: green;
  width: 55px;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="testbox"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I have downloaded chrome non beta version. Your code is also working and mine too. Beta version also has setInterval() and setTimer() issues. I dont know why. 

PS: My +1 does not show because I have not earned enough points yet.

Thank you for your feedback.